# Remove a network printer with Python's wmi module?

Tags: python, windows, printing, wmi, python-module

For starters, [here's the WMI module I'm referring to](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html).

I've tried many combinations of code, and understand how to remove network printers with wmic from the command line, as well as a basic understanding on how to remove network printers with wmi in VB, etc. but I still can't figure out how to do so in this python module.

Does anyone have experience with this? I'm testing with PyDev in Eclipse, typically on a Windows 7 machine (which this program will be used for along with XP), but also on Windows 8.

Here's some code I've tried:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()

c.win32_printer("\\\\server\\printer").delete
```

And I get the following error:

```
wmi.x_wmi_invalid_query: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147217385, 'OLE error 0x80041017', None, None)>
```

Comment: Try using the `Delete_` method like so `c.win32_printer("\\\\server\\printer").Delete_`

Comment: @RRUZ Exactly the same error.

Comment: Can you access a property of the printer instance using this syntax `c.win32_printer("\\\\server\\printer").DEVICEID`? I ask because I'm familiarized with the WMI but not why this python module.

Comment: @RRUZ No, I cannot. However, the following code does work:
`for printer in c.win32_printer():`
`print printer.DEVICEID`

Comment: And this work `for printer in c.win32_printer(): printer.Delete_`?

Comment: @RRUZ I'm not going to delete all my printers, but if I perform that command with `if printer.servername == "\\\\server"` in between, it still does not work. No errors, but does not delete printers on that server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend (who probably wishes to remain unnamed) found a solution!

```
for printer in c.win32_printer():
    if printer.DEVICEID == "\\\\server\\printer":
    printer.delete_()
```

For some reason, the server name (and possibly printer name) seem to be case-sensitive, so keep an eye out for that. I'd guess it's because python is case sensitive, and it's comparing via python, not WMI.

Comment: Helpful, and that works on other things as well (IP4 routing table in my case)